# How does the flash layer interact with the flex layer in a multiple layer design?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

Don't know if the flash layer on the view stack contain only the compiled flash swf file

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Are you talking about (visual) layers as in objects on the display list or in a more abstract sense, layers of the runtime/platform?

Answer (score 0):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSFD77A256-0DE1-46c7-86FB-CC4A8AE2EAA6.html

In general it's very easy to work with flash components, or any custom work you design in flash, within flex.  You can communicate and control the sub-components as if you were in flash.   The only exception is loading an as2 flash piece in flex or as3, then you need to use localconnection to handle the communication between.   Not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, would help to elaborate.